# Is there any integration of a defined function that could not be express as a convergent infinite series?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any integration of a defined function that could not be express as a convergent infinite series?Like if it could be getting a divergent series as an answer

I wonder if the answer is a yes or no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about power series, any function expressible by a  power series that converges in some open interval $(a,b)$ is analytic in a (complex) neighbourhood of that interval and so are its derivative and antiderivative.  So a counterexample would be a any function 
that is integrable but not analytic.  For an example of a function that is smooth but nowhere analytic, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function)